# MKStoreKit Suddenly can not validate product

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have been using MKStoreKit for long time but today I got the error below from 7 different users while they were trying to make purhcase. What is going on?I am wondering what is the cause of this without any change on the code.

```
[MKStoreKit startValidatingAppStoreReceiptWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke (MKStoreKit.m:366)
NSInvalidArgumentException: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
__exceptionPreprocess + 1323364
objc_exception_throw + 34084
_CFThrowFormattedException + 900248
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 81868
+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 81480
__66-[MKStoreKit startValidatingAppStoreReceiptWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke (MKStoreKit.m:366)
__75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 40292
__49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 140984
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 953244
-[NSBlockOperation main] + 166032
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 99520
_dispatch_client_callout + 6672
```

Comment: the question is if you are create the purchase manually in itunes or import them like with script, maybe something is broken ?

Comment: I have not changed a single line or any version. The app was working for 3 months with no problem. Suddenly 7 users failed to purchase.